# How to get message from javax websocket server when connection has been opened

Tags: javascript, java, jakarta-ee, websocket, java-websocket

I had been wrote a simple javax websocket app. I'm trying to send data from @OnOpen method via session to client like this

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {

    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Client connected");

}
```

then I'm trying to recieve it, but got **undefined** on client

```
        ws.onopen = function(event) {
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = event.message;
        };
```

or

```
        ws.onopen = function(event) {
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = event.data;
        };
```

Could we get it?!

add: also a same thing with @OnError

Comment: perhaps you should use onmessage handler to get the message.

Comment: Yes, I know, but the question is could we do it with these methods and if no what we could do with them

Comment: for example as per documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket onopen event indicates that connection is ready to send/receive the data. it is meaningful, for example, if you are going to send some data from your client, since connection establishment is async event.

Comment: Yes, but how we could use it in javax context for practicle things, I also learnt what it's doing, but when I was trying to right something helpful in the code then the result wasn't expected

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [JSR 356](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jsr356.html), if you read the OnOpen part, there are parameters like session, configs and path params but there is nothing you get for a message from the client. So maybe you can use path params to get the data?